# Converting formula to disjunctive normal form

Tags: propositional-calculus, disjunctive-normal-form

> Convert
>   $$\neg(P\to Q)\lor\neg(P\lor\neg(R\lor S))$$
>   to DNF.

This is what I've already done:
$$\neg(\neg P\lor\neg Q)\lor(\neg P\lor\neg(\neg R\lor\neg S))$$

And from this point, I'm not sure how to proceed. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Using [SymPy Live](http://live.sympy.org), `p, q , r, s = symbols('p q  r s'); print to_dnf(Not(p >> q) | Not(p | Not(r | s)))` produces `Or(And(Not(p), r), And(Not(p), s), And(Not(q), p))`.

Answer (score 3):

You've made mistakes in failing to use DeMorgans.

First, I use, like you did,  the equivalence of $P\rightarrow Q \equiv \lnot P \lor Q$, and second, I use DeMorgan's Law in step $(1);$

DeMorgan's is used also in step $(2)$ below;

and in step $(3)$ I use the distributive property:

$$\begin{align}\neg(P\to Q)\lor\neg(P\lor\neg(R\lor S))
&\equiv \lnot(\lnot P \lor Q) \lor (\lnot P \land \lnot \lnot (R\lor S))\tag{1}\\ \\ 
&\equiv (P \land \lnot Q) \lor (\lnot P \land (R \lor S))\tag{2}\\ \\ 
&\equiv (P\land \lnot Q) \lor (\lnot P \land R) \lor (\lnot P \land S)\tag{3}\\ \\
\end{align}$$

And we now have Disjunction Normal Form, in $(3)$.